# vb.net My.Settings class Category and Description

Tags: vb.net, settings, propertygrid, my.settings

I am having issues with finding out exactly what my path forward should be. I would like to allow my users to be able to update the user scoped settings in the Settings.settings file in my application. I have created a form which displays these settings through a propertygrid. I would like to be able to show the description for each and maybe even assign them a category for better organization. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Here is an example someone else had posted, but you have to make sure to include all settings. I would be afraid that I might miss one. [my-settings-and-descriptions-and-getting-them-into-a-propertygrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220193/my-settings-and-descriptions-and-getting-them-into-a-propertygrid)

I guess that isn't the best reason to not use it. I also could not understand how to fully implement this option. There is also the other side of which I would like to be able to put the settings into a category instead of *"Misc"* like visual studio does by default.

Thanks for the help ahead of time.

J-Mo

Comment: *"I would be afraid that I might miss one"*. If that's a genuine concern then you may as well give up programming now because it's always possible that you'll miss something no matter what you do. *"I also could not understand how to fully implement this option"*. That's too vague to be of any use to us. Do what you can and then, when you encounter a specific issue, provide all the information relevant to that. That's what SO is for: specific issues.

Comment: Well as much as I appreciate your response, that was a little bit on the rude side. I am still learning. When I said, _"I would be afraid that I might miss one", I should have asked, **Is there a better way to accomplish this?**. I will continue on as I always have. I will research these boards, but I will stay away from posting. Thanks @jmcilhinney for your awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

### My Solution

My goal was to be able to display all of the ***user-scoped*** settings from the settings.settings file and allow the user to be able to edit them.

[Settings Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN5WV.png)

I added the below code directly into the **Settings.Designer.vb** file. *I know that moving forward I will have to add all of my settings manually so as to not regenerate the code.*

The added lines were:

1. `Global.System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute("Saves the location of the CMLs Form Location")`
2. `Global.System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute("Location")`

```
<Global.System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute(),
         Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),
         Global.System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute("Saves the CMLs Form Location"),
         Global.System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute("Location"),
         Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("0, 0")>
        Public Property FormCMLsLocation() As Global.System.Drawing.Point
            Get
                Return CType(Me("FormCMLsLocation"), Global.System.Drawing.Point)
            End Get
            Set
                Me("FormCMLsLocation") = Value
            End Set
        End Property
```

This will need to be completed for each property in the class.

The Property Grid in the form was limited to the User Scope with the below code.

```
Public Class FormUserSettings
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Dim userAttr As New System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute
        Dim attrs As New System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection(userAttr)

        Dim myProxy As New ProxySettings

        If PropertyGrid IsNot Nothing Then
            'PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = myProxy
            PropertyGrid.SelectedObject = My.Settings
        End If
        PropertyGrid.BrowsableAttributes = attrs

    End Sub
End Class
```

Let me know if you have a better way of accomplishing this. It is not my preferred method with how much could go wrong.

-J-Mo